# Which one of the following two Sankalpa Mantras is correct?

Tags: mantras, sankalpa

Sandhyavandanam,Puja or a Japa always generally begins with a Sankalpa.

I've found the following two Sankalpa Mantras on web.

> Mantra 1)
>
> "Mamopatha Samastha, duritha kshaya dwara, Shri Parameswara
>   preethyartham...
>
> Mantra2)
>
> Mamo partha samastha durithakshaya dwara , Sri Parameshwara
>   preethyartham...

Mantra 1 is found [here](http://vishuji.org/Kamokarishi.htm) & Mantra 2 [here](http://stotraratna.sathyasaibababrotherhood.org/pm20.htm).

I have not given the complete mantras as it is not needed for my purpose.

As can be seen the mantras differ only by a word **patta/partha.**

My question-Which one of the two mantras is the correct one?

Another allied question-What are the meanings of the words "patta" and "partha"?

Comment: It is actually Mama-Upatta which means my (sins) gathered together. When it is joined according to Sandhi rules it becomes Mamopatta.

Comment: Thanks Surya.So some websites are teaching  wrong mantras?And btw do partha have any meaning?

Comment: @Yogi i know that .As i have said in the question itself ,only the beginning parts of the mantras are given.My only query is on the usage of the word patta/partha and which one is the correct one to use among them.

Comment: mamopatta is correct one which means the 'papa karma done by the yajman(person doing sankalpa).

Comment: Can anyone tell what "partha" means in sanskrit?

Comment: pArtha is arjuna. In Sanskrit it means prince. Whoever referenced it in the mantra (in the website or book) knows neither the mantra nor the language. Stick with what your upadesa guru taught you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is the correct one.

mama + upātta samasta duritakṣayadvārā śrī parameśvara prītyartham

mama + upātta = mamopātta

upātta is to acquire.

partha is name of arjuna  and other meanings can also be said. but the correct one is mamopatta.

The meaning of the line goes as To please lord parameshwara, mama upaata = given to me or obtained by me, samasta duritakshayadwara, through decreasing the sins

so as a whole, it goes as Through the decreasing of sins obtained by me or given to me and to please the lord parameshwara, so and so karyam like saayam sandhyaam upasishye.i am doing evening sandhya worship

Answer (score 2):

Partha means that matter which belongs to earth (prithvi). Once the Prana leaves the body we call it Parthiva shareera. Arjuna represents that Jeevatma and hence he is also called Partha and Krishna being the charioteer of this Partha (Jeevatma) he is called Parthasarathy.